# On the Hilbert Curve

Tags: general-topology

(1)A mapping  \begin{equation}{f}\colon{X}\rightarrow{Y}\end{equation} is said to be a homeomorphism of it is (1) f is a bijection (2) f is continuous (3)the inverse mapping f inverse is also continuous.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism#Definition

The bijection \begin{equation}R^2\leftrightarrow R\end{equation} between the unit square and the Hilbert curve should be a homeomorphism unless the definition includes differentiability as an essential criterion[or perhaps if the inverse function is not continuous].
Requesting a clarification to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a homeomorphism should preserve topological properties. If you remove one point $p$ from $\mathbb{R}$, then a homeomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ should restrict to a homeomorphism $$\phi:\mathbb{R} \setminus \{p\} \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{\phi(p)\}.$$ This cannot be since $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{p\}$ is disconnected whereas $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{\phi(p)\}$ is connected. Moreover, the hilbert curve is not bijective since it is not necessarily injective.

Comment: We may consider a 2D surface like our unit square and remove a point from it.Next we take a closed curve round this  point and try to shrink it to a point. The curve lands on the point that has been removed. Therefore we have not been able to shrink the curve to a point on the remaining surface.The unit square is no more simply connected.

Comment: That is correct. It is still path-connected, though.

Comment: The Hilbert curve is the limiting curve in the process of its development as we decrease the size of the pixels.We know that limit is unique. We take two distinct points on the real line and follow their images on the unit square as the pseudo Hilbert curves proceed towards the limit. Each point will hit a single point on the Hilbert curve.Let two points on the real line we started from  hit the same limit point on the final curve[Hilbert curve]. In such an event. Interestingly  we have a many to one mapping R to R since the Hilbert curve itself can represent the real line.

Comment: (in continuation)Considering the Hilbert curve each point on it sits on only one point in the square. We do have a bijection unless the Hilbert were of a self intersecting nature. In this case the uniqueness of limit would have been  broken.

Comment: An Intuitive Speculation:In the built up process we round up the corners of all the intermediate curves[pseudo Hilbert curves]to make the intermediate curves[pseudo Hilbert curves] smooth.If the limit curve exists the curve standing at the limit, that is ,our modified Hilbert curve should be a smooth curve since a all intermediate stages we had smooth curves.

Comment: @AnamitraPalit The Hilbert curve (or any other space filling curve $[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$) is not injective, because otherwise it would be an homeomorphism and that cannot happen because those spaces have different (covering) dimension